# VSCODE find content in any folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a means in VSCODE for 'find in files' to work from a specific folder? It seems it only works in the current folder open in Visual Studio.

I currently have to open Notepad++ and use it's find in files to search for specific content within a given folder.

thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to search outside the workspace.

Comment: @Wosi Do you happen to know if there are any open feature requests for this?